# Find the difference between two fields in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table which stores monthly billing information.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[billing_history](
[id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[reading_date] [date] NOT NULL,
[reading] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[consumer_id] [int] NOT NULL)
```

The consumer_id is a foreign key referencing the consumer details table.

What i want is to subtract every customer current reading from the reading of the previous month. This would generate the current bill. Any ideas.

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: `the reading of the previous month` : there's one and only one entry in billing_history each month for one customer ?

Comment: Yes only one entry for every customer Each Month

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something similar to this, where you would replace the values of the month/year that you want to return:

```
select b1.consumer_id,
  sum(b1.reading - isnull(b2.reading, 0)) Total
from billing_history b1
left join billing_history b2
  on b1.consumer_id = b2.consumer_id
  and month(b2.reading_date) =12
  and year(b2.reading_date) = 2012
where month(b1.reading_date) = 1
  and year(b1.reading_date) = 2013
group by b1.consumer_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72971/2).

If you don't want to pass in the values of the `month` and `year` to search and you only want the current/previous month, then you could use something similar to this using a CTE:

```
;with cur as
(
  select consumer_id,
    reading,
    month(getdate()) curMonth,
    year(getdate()) curYear,
    case when month(getdate()) = 1 then 12 else month(getdate()) -1 end preMonth,
    case when month(getdate()) = 1 then year(getdate())-1 else year(getdate()) end preYear
  from billing_history
  where month(reading_date) = month(getdate())
    and year(reading_date) = year(getdate())
)
select c.consumer_id, 
  sum(c.reading - isnull(pre.reading, 0)) TotalReading
from cur c
left join billing_history pre
  on c.consumer_id = pre.consumer_id
  and month(pre.reading_date) = c.preMonth
  and year(pre.reading_date) = c.preYear
group by c.consumer_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83c14/36)

This version gets both the current/previous month and year values to be used.  If you are not familiar with CTE syntax, this can also be written as:

```
select c.consumer_id, 
  sum(c.reading - isnull(pre.reading, 0)) TotalReading
from
(
  select consumer_id,
    reading,
    month(getdate()) curMonth,
    year(getdate()) curYear,
    case when month(getdate()) = 1 then 12 else month(getdate()) -1 end preMonth,
    case when month(getdate()) = 1 then year(getdate())-1 else year(getdate()) end preYear
  from billing_history
  where month(reading_date) = month(getdate())
    and year(reading_date) = year(getdate())
) c
left join billing_history pre
  on c.consumer_id = pre.consumer_id
  and month(pre.reading_date) = c.preMonth
  and year(pre.reading_date) = c.preYear
group by c.consumer_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83c14/38).

As you can see in my queries I used the aggregate function `SUM()` and a `GROUP BY` on the `consumer_id`.  I did this in the event you had more than one reading per customer. If you know you will only have one reading per month, then you could remove the aggregate.

Comment: I have another table where i have this slab for commerical/domestic consumers for the number of units consumed. For e.g 50 units * 4 for a domestic consumer and *10 for a commerical consumer. How do i multiply those values to the resulting reading of the above query.

Comment: @user2018756: If that's something that you can't apply this answer to, you should probably consider asking a new question. We tend to keep things simple on this site: one problem, one question.

Comment: @user2018756 If you not able to add the other tables, then I would suggest asking another question with your query that you are using and then the new details.  That would be the easiest way to get help.  :)